# Issue with containedBy in Supabase Flutter Integration

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, supabase

I am encountering an issue while attempting to utilize the containedBy method in the Supabase Flutter integration. Below is the relevant code snippet:

```dart
      var query = Supabase.instance.client.from('jobs').select(
          '*,city(name_ar,name_en,id,country!inner(id,name_ar,name_en)),job_category_rel:job_category_rel!inner(id, category!inner(id,name_ar,name_en))');
      if (widget.countryList.isNotEmpty) {
        //TODO create a logic chat filters data based on country id
        query = query.containedBy("city.country.id", widget.countryList);
      }
      final data = await query;
```

The issue arises when attempting to apply the containedBy filter on the city.country.id field. It's important to note that widget.countryList is of type `List<int>`, while city.country.id in the database is of type `int8`.

The encountered error is as follows:

```
Error fetching data: PostgrestException(message: "failed to parse filter (containedBy.{3})" (line 1, column 1), code: PGRST100, details: unexpected "c" expecting "not" or operator (eq, gt, ...), hint: null)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to find rows where `city.country.id` is in the array.

For that, you can use the `inFilter` instead of `containedBy`.

```dart
query = query.inFilter("city.country.id", widget.countryList);
```